# WarrantyTrack setup in XAAMPP

Tags: xampp

I'm trying to setup [WarrantyTrack](http://warrantytrack.org/) using XAMPP installed on a thumb drive. I tried contacting the software designer through his website  but he directed me here for assistance.

When I try to start it, I get this error:

> A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in V:\xampp\htdocs\dbConnect.php on line 2

Other sites work in this XAMPP installation, but this one continues to give me this error. I am very new to XAMPP. Can you give me some idea of how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a 'warning' and not a very critical error.

The reason for this is that every main PHP page includes a line of code to start a session. However, this should be done by first checking if a session had already started. Since the WarrantyTrack system does not do this you see the warning.

The easiest solution for you is to turn off XAMPP's warnings for PHP. I'm not sure if XAMPP offers some sort of GUI for doing this but you can always do it from PHP's configuration file.

This file is called php.ini and [here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160859/turn-php-error-reporting-off-in-xampp) to show how this is done.

The better way of course is to go for the newer version of WarrantyTrack but the newer version is not yet released for public use. Furthermore, the newer version uses PostgreSQL for the back-end.